# How to show available disks on a Linux system?

Tags: linux, awk

If i run **fdisk -l** I get an output as:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003ad9d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1306    10490413+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2            1307        2612    10490445   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
        255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
        Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
        Disk identifier: 0x0003ad9d

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1               1        1306    10490413+  83  Linux
    /dev/sdb2            1307        2612    10490445   83  Linux
```

How can I just show the disks available on system such that they may with a space between them as:

> /dev/sda        /dev/sdb        /dev/sdc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipes to redirect the output

```
 fdisk -l | grep ^Disk | awk -F:  '{ print $1 }' |  awk -F" "  '{ print $2 }'
```

- fisk -l: get the full disk output
- grep Disk: filter the line starting
  with Disk
- awk -F:  '{ print $1 }': get first part where the separator is ":"
- awk -F" "  '{ print $2 }': get the second part where the separator is space

Comment: In some blatant shell golf, I came up with this: `fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep -o '(/dev/[^:]*):' |awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: `fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep -o '(/dev/[^:]*):' | egrep -o '([^:]*)'`

One better :)

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions | egrep -o '.d.' | sort | uniq` works on my machine, but I'm not sure how hacky it is.  Probably fails on machines with more than sda-sdz :)

Comment: This doesn't take in to account things live device mapper partitions.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

or

```
ls /dev/sd*
```

This will list all available partitions!

Comment: I wish I could give half an upvote.  ;)  'cat /proc/partitions' works fine, 'ls /dev/sd*' will sometimes work, but won;t necessarily list all drives. so, for example:
<pre>
root>cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 202     0    5242880 xvda
 202    16     262144 xvdb
 202    32    5242880 xvdc

root>ls /dev/sd*
ls: cannot access /dev/sd*: No such file or directory

</pre>

Comment: @Don: Use backticks instead of <pre> in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perl version:

```
fdisk -l | perl -n -e 'if (m{^Disk (\/.*):})  { print $1," "} END { print "\n"}'
```

prints:

```
/dev/sda /dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows mounted partitions as a space-delimited list:

```
echo $(mount -t ext2,ext3 | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

You can add other filesystem types.

Comment: It will shows only the mounted devices, what about the another ones?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few other alternatives, if you can make certain assumptions (I like /proc/partitions, though, as long as you're filtering on the major numbers so you don't pick up LVM volumes, etc)

Assuming your disks all are local (ie, not SAN):

```
user@host [/home/q0px]
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec  5 01:27 pci-0000:00:1f.1-ide-0:0 -> ../../hda
```

If your partitions all have UUIDs (works for SAN devices, too)

```
user@host [/home/q0px]
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec  5 01:27 dc13d5cf-ba98-4339-99c5-0136177f7e22 -> ../../cciss/c0d0p1
```

If your partitiona all have labels (also orks for SAN devices):

```
user@host [/home/q0px]
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec  5 01:27 boot -> ../../cciss/c0d0p1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use only one command, like:

```
    awk '/[a-z]$/ {print $4}' /proc/partitions
```

or if you have md or dm devices and want to display only sata (sdx) drives:

```
    awk '$4 ~ /^sd.$/ { print $4 }' /proc/partitions
```

Also not so pretty, still one-liner, it uses more commands, but works:

```
    cat /proc/partitions | awk '{print $4}' | grep sd[a-z] | grep -v [0-9]
```

Just my 2 cents... Hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

i guess commands like the one u used, or df(which lists the devices while showing the free and used space) will not output the data in space delimited fashion as u want. U need to use a string processing command like sed 'piped' to the output of previous disk commands and get the desired oputput.

-AD.

Comment: Uv xceded teh tweet len lim.